# Vue : Store dynamic number of inputs in an dynamic two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I get an multi dimensional array named `response` from back-end and what I'm trying to do is to create several text-fields depending on the number of element I have in response (each response element has some inner elements like response[0][0] and response[0][1] that each of them is a object contains caption,name,etc for each text-field. for example `response[0][0].name` get name of response[0][0] element).
What I want is to bind these text-fields to an other two dimensional array named `data` so I can get value of them and use them as I want.
Here's the code:

```
 <v-layout  row wrap v-for="(row,i) in response" :key = "i">
      <v-layout  v-for="(col,j) in row" :key = "j">
         <v-text-field
          :name = "col.name"
          :label = "col.caption"
          v-model="data[i][j]"//I think somehow i should create data[i][j] element 
                               first,like data[i] =[] 
          >
         </v-text-field>
      </v-layout>
  </v-layout>
```

And script is :

```
data () {
 return {
  data: [],
  response: []
 }
},
 mounted: function () {
   //get response from back-end
 }
```

I'm new to Vue and javascript, any help would be appreciate...
please comment If it's not clear.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the response object?

Comment: each response[i][j] is a object that should have  a corresponding text-field.  for example response[0][0] is a object that contains two fields. response[0][0].name for name of the text-field and response[0][0].caption for caption of text-field(title). 
so response[0][0] is {"name","caption"}@SeifSayed

Answer (score 0):

should work... can you clarify what the issue is? is it matter of generating the response array?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: [
      [{
          name: 'name00',
          caption: 'caption00'
        },
        {
          name: 'name01',
          caption: 'caption01'
        }
      ],
      [{
          name: 'name10',
          caption: 'caption10'
        },
        {
          name: 'name11',
          caption: 'caption11'
        }
      ]
    ],
    response: [
      ['',''],
      ['','']
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.5/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(i, ii) in data" :key="ii">
    <div v-for="(j, jj) in i" :key="jj">
      {{j.name}}
      
      <input v-model="response[ii][jj]" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{response}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: actually response array objects serve as meta data of fields of a form.  And there are many fields in a form and consequently there are many objects in response(not just two objects). Each of this objects contains meta data of a field including name,caption,... So first of all i need to generate these fields based on meta data getting from response. then i must bind value of each text-field to a data array. i don't know size of response, i get it from back-end. So I do not know how many field are there. then i have to make data array dynamically. i can't initialize it,just like you did.

Comment: can you provide a semi-working version with some more data to better understand what's going on?